# Upload image from Android to mysql database with raspberry pi serving as server

Tags: php, android, mysql, raspberry-pi2

```
 <?php
// Create connection
include 'DatabaseConfig.php';
$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
 $DefaultId = 0;
 $ImageData = $_POST['image_path'];
 $ImageName = $_POST['image_name'];
 $GetOldIdSQL ="SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY id ASC";
 $Query = mysqli_query($conn,$GetOldIdSQL);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Query)){
  $DefaultId = $row['id'];
 }
 $ImagePath = "/home/pi/Pictures/images/$DefaultId.jpg";
 $ServerURL = "https://localhost/$ImagePath";
 $InsertSQL = "insert into table1 (image_path,image_name) values ('$ServerURL','$ImageName')";
 if(mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSQL)){
  file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($ImageData));
  echo "Your Image Has Been Uploaded.";
 }
 mysqli_close($conn);
}
else{
 echo "Not Uploaded";
}
?>
```

this is the php code which is been called from android application for uploading the image in server and saving the information of image in database made in phpmyadmin. All the mysql connection information written are correct but the imagepath where the images would be uploaded is wrong I believe. Also the serverURL provided may be wrong.

Can someone help me to check the path and URL written for uploading on raspberry pi server(using LAMP server) as I'm unable to do it.

Secondly, help me whether the location of image, i.e. a folder present in raspberry pi, to upload is correct or not.